# "Если отец-командир переусердствует – трубка растрескается". Тип предложения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, сложное-предложение

> Если отец-командир переусердствует – трубка растрескается.

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение неоднородного состава. Верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь простые предложения связаны союзом, поэтому это предложение союзное. А вот если убрать ***если***, то у нас получается бессоюзное сложное предложение, в котором тире передает как раз значение союза *если*.

Comment: Отец-командир переусердствует – трубка растрескается, когда и вовсе рассыплется.

Подходит к БСП?

Comment: Не совсем. Здесь два вида связи: бессоюзная и подчинительная. Это немного другой раздел синтаксиса.

Answer (score 3):

Это условное придаточное, а не БСП. Есть союз ***если.***